# Как написать максимально эффективное приложение на laravel?

Tags: laravel

Всем привет. Вопрос следующий, хочу написать rest api используя laravel в сочетании с обычным классическим приложением, и задумался, как написать приложение максимально эффективное с точки зрения быстроты обработки запросов и работы с БД… В общем хотелось бы узнать у опытных разработчиков:

- Какую версию laravel стоит взять?
- Какую версию MySQL подтянуть или есть более быстрые СУБД?
- Какую версию PHP? Стоит ли именно на 8 или пока не стоит?
- Также интересует вопрос добавления в проект кастумных css, js файлов, как лучше и эффективней работать с ними? Миксовать или просто создать в паблике assets и прямыми ссылками в блейды добавить?
- Ну и что будет быстрей, эффективней работать, Tailwind или Bootstrap

PS: хотелось бы получить объективный взгляд на подобную проблему, а не просто «бери последнюю версию и не парься»… Также стоит отметить, что проект подразумевается достаточно простой, учебный так сказать, поэтому нетривиальных задач не предусмотрено…

Comment: по первым трем пунктам берите актуальную стабильную версию. По 4-5 не ясно к чему, у вас в начале написано что проект - rest api.

Comment: _rest api используя laravel в сочетании с обычным классическим приложением_ это типа обычный сайт у которого ещё будет api? _«бери последнюю версию и не парься»_ это и есть объективный взгляд. Посоветовал бы начать делать, вместо подобных вопросов, только время тратите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> эффективное с точки зрения быстроты обработки запросов и работы с БД

Это в большей степени зависит от размера вашей бд, структуры бд, количеством запросов к бд и самих запросов, чем от поставленных вами вопросов.

> а не просто «бери последнюю версию и не парься»…

Естественно, берите последние версии. Или вы ожидаете ответа типо: "берите `laravel 5`, все следующие версии тормозят"? Но так это не работает.

> хотелось бы получить объективный взгляд на подобную проблему

Вы пытаетесь все идеализировать. Даже если вы найдете самые быстрые библиотеки для вашего простого проекта, это выиграет вам от силы десятую долю секунды. Это не стоит этого. Вам нужно найти баланс удобства программирования и производительности. Для простого проекта удобство на первом месте. Иначе если упарываться в производительность, то вам вообще не нужен php.

Пример: Есть проект. Используются самые модные и производительные технологии. Потрачено куча времени на проект. А это всего лишь сайт-визитка. И пользователю все равно, открывается он за 0.6 сек или за 0.7 сек.